# addEventListener giving error in typescript

Tags: typescript, react-hooks, addeventlistener

```
const [locked, setLocked] = useState<string>("pending");

const unlockHandler = (e: string) => {
  setLocked(e);
};

useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener("unlockProtocol", unlockHandler);
  return () => window.removeEventListener("unlockProtocol", unlockHandler);
}, []);
```

window.addEventListener("unlockProtocol", unlockHandler) gives error as

> Type '(e: string) => void' is not assignable to type 'EventListener'.

Answer (score 0):

callback of `addEventListener` expects an `Event` and not a string.

YOu should use appropriate types:

```js
  const [locked, setLocked] = useState<string>("pending");


  const unlockHandler = (e: {target:{name:string}}) => {
    setLocked(e.target.name);
  };
  
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("unlockProtocol", unlockHandler);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("unlockProtocol", unlockHandler);
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

`EventListener` is typed as follows:

```
interface EventListener {
    (evt: Event): void;
}
```

– [reference](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/630012a6a79b3a811269c6ddd66310f49d2c02f5/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L5113-L5119)

It does not expect a `string` as the first argument but an [`Event`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/630012a6a79b3a811269c6ddd66310f49d2c02f5/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L5034). As a result you should write your event handler so that it can accept an [`Event`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/630012a6a79b3a811269c6ddd66310f49d2c02f5/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L5034) as its first argument. Your function may then compute something from the event, potentially it's [type](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/630012a6a79b3a811269c6ddd66310f49d2c02f5/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L5079), to set your locked state.

## Long answer

Let's figure out your error right from the bottom.

The type for `window.addEventListener` is as follows:

```
/** A window containing a DOM document; the document property points to the DOM document loaded in that window. */
interface Window extends EventTarget, AnimationFrameProvider, GlobalEventHandlers, WindowEventHandlers, WindowLocalStorage, WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope, WindowSessionStorage {
    [...]

    addEventListener<K extends keyof WindowEventMap>(type: K, listener: (this: Window, ev: WindowEventMap[K]) => any, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions): void;
    addEventListener(type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions): void;

    [...]
}
```

– [reference](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/630012a6a79b3a811269c6ddd66310f49d2c02f5/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L17297-L17298)

You've passed a string with value `unlockProtocol` to the first argument. This does not match any key on [`WindowEventMap`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/630012a6a79b3a811269c6ddd66310f49d2c02f5/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L17162) so the first overload isn't matched but the second overload is. As a result, the type for your use of `window.addEventListener` will be:

```
addEventListener(type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions): void;
```

Your handler, with the type inferred to be `(e: string) => void`, will need to match `EventListenerOrEventListenerObject`. The type of that is:

```
type EventListenerOrEventListenerObject = EventListener | EventListenerObject;
```

– [reference](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/630012a6a79b3a811269c6ddd66310f49d2c02f5/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L18690)

`EventListener` and `EventListenerObject` are typed as follows:

```
interface EventListener {
    (evt: Event): void;
}

interface EventListenerObject {
    handleEvent(object: Event): void;
}
```

– [reference](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/630012a6a79b3a811269c6ddd66310f49d2c02f5/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L5113-L5119)

We're now at the same place as the error TypeScript gave you:

> Type '(e: string) => void' is not assignable to type 'EventListener'.

From `EventListener`'s type it does not expect a `string` as the first argument but an [`Event`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/630012a6a79b3a811269c6ddd66310f49d2c02f5/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L5034). As a result you should write your event handler so that it can accept an [`Event`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/630012a6a79b3a811269c6ddd66310f49d2c02f5/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L5034) as its first argument. Your function may then compute something from the event, potentially it's [type](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/630012a6a79b3a811269c6ddd66310f49d2c02f5/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L5079), to set your locked state.